# Why can I declare array with a constant size in some cases and not others?

Tags: c++, arrays

Im trying to create a struct that includes a 2d array along with some member functions.

When I write:

```
struct Board {
    const int BOARDSIZE = 8;

    bool data[BOARDSIZE][BOARDSIZE];
};
```

I get "a nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific object." However, when I write:

```
const int BOARDSIZE = 8;

struct Board {
    bool data[BOARDSIZE][BOARDSIZE];
};
```

or:

```
struct Board {
    bool data[8][8];
};
```

there is no error. I've searched around and cant figure out why it wont accept one and not the other. I'd rather not declare BOARDSIZE as a global variable because I dont want it just floating around in a large project but I also dont want to have to write 8 every time a member function of the struct needs the board size for flexability's sake down the line.

Is there a way to have a local variable that represents the size of the board?

Comment: The general rule is that the number in brackets must be a number and cannot be a variable. Apparently there are also some specific exceptions where a const variable is allowed. Probably nobody thought to make your first code an exception.

Comment: `BOARDSIZE` in your 1st snippet is a non-static member. I.e. it is "tied" to an instance of the class (this is the meaning of your error message). You can achieve what you need by making it `static inline const int BOARDSIZE = 8;`

Comment: An ancient trick (from C) is `enum {BOARDSIZE = 8}; bool[BOARDSIZE][BOARDSIZE];`.   Technically, however, `BOARDSIZE` is not a variable though - it is a named enumerator.

Comment: Array size must be *compile time* constant, not just a value of variable declared with `const` quilifier.

Comment: @Peter which ancient C had `enums`?

Comment: Let's say I added a constructor to your `Board` class: `Board(int t_size) : BOARDSIZE(t_size) { }`. How big is a `Board` object supposed to be? There isn't actually a guarantee that `BOARDSIZE` is always `8`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, one alternative would be using a static const member variable; something like this:

```
struct Board {
    static const int BOARDSIZE = 8;

    bool data[BOARDSIZE][BOARDSIZE];
};
```

Comment: and it better be `constexpr`, not just `const`, though for this case it's an equivalent. `const` still may be assigned at runtime

Answer (score 1):

While @Jakub Skop answer would do the job. I would recommend, you to consider creating `Board` template. Which will make your code more generic. Which will give you reusability.

```
template<size_t s>
struct Grid {
    int arr[s][s];
};

Grid<8> grid;
```

Comment: Do not overcomplicate. If OP wants to, e.g. implement Chess, why would they ever need a board other than 8x8?

Comment: @tos-1 you'd be surprised, there are dozens of derived games

Answer (score 0):

You need a compile-time evaluated expression. Your options are

```
struct BoardCPP11 {
    static constexpr int BOARDSIZE = 8;  // everywhere will be compile-time

    bool data[BOARDSIZE][BOARDSIZE];
};

struct BoardCPP98 {
    static const int BOARDSIZE = 8;  // it's still a variable

    bool data[BOARDSIZE][BOARDSIZE]; //  but expression can be compile-time
};

struct BoardOldSkool {
    enum { BOARDSIZE = 8 };    // is an non-entity, a name for numeric value

    bool data[BOARDSIZE][BOARDSIZE]; 
};
```

The reason why a non-static cannot work is because an object usually would be created during runtime (unless it's a `constexpr`, anno C++11). A non-static memeber would be created at that time too. Before C++11 only value of an integral global `const` variable, a literal, or an enumerator can be considered as a compile-time value for array size, this includes static class members.

And for template geeks

```
template <unsigned BOARDSIZE>
  struct BoardBase { bool data[BOARDSIZE][BOARDSIZE]; };
  using Board = BoardBase <8>;
```

Template parameters are always compile time. I'd be partitial to this approach, but this bloats header files and requires extreme care. New C++ feature, modules, solve this issue.